# Stop Xscreensaver from locking screen once screensaver starts

Tags: lubuntu, screensaver, lock-screen, xscreensaver

I have installed Lubuntu 12.04 and was wondering if there was a way to keep it from locking the screen when the screensaver starts?
The "lock screen after X minutes" box is unchecked, so that is not causing the problem. Does anyone know the solution for this problem? I'm not worried about security, so i don't need it locked.

Answer (score 12):

I think you have to disable the "lock" in two different places. First, open the power manager. You can click on the power icon in the panel and select "preferences" or it should also be in Menu -> Preferences -> Power Manager

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35272968/site/2012-06-15-192224_740x482_scrot.png]

De-select "Lock screen...." under the "Extended" menu tab.

Second, open screensaver preferences. Menu -> Preferences -> Screensaver.

Again, de-select "lock screen..." at the bottom of the window.

CREDIT: http://lubuntutips.blogspot.com/2012/06/lubuntu-screensaver-lock.html

Answer (score 6):

I recommend you simply remove xscreensaver by typing `sudo apt-get remove xscreensaver` This will solve your problem, if you don't need a screensaver,  your screen still turns black by your energy safe settings.

Comment: Granted most screensavers dont do what they need to.  moire2 is a good example of ones that do work.  screen burn in is still a problem even on lcd's   I have a pc that the right monitor is rotated and has a scroll bar on the right side of the screen about 12-16 hrs a day.  I set the screen saver for 10 min and blank for 20 so that moire can excersize out that scroll bar burn in.  after about 3 months of use like that you could easily see where the scroll bar and other buttons were due to burn in.

Answer (score 2):

On a fresh Lubuntu 18.10 install, I went to Preferences > LXQt settings > Session settings and unchecked `Lock screen before suspending/hibernating` and that seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 1):

For default setup of Lubuntu 14.04, the locking can be disabled via Preferences -> Light Locker Settings. In my case, "Automatically lock the session" was "Never", yet the session was still being locked after around 10 mins of inactivity. So I turned "OFF" the "Enable light-locker" setting, which did the thing for me. I also disabled all "locks" in Power Management as in @algebralives's answer. Don't know if it was required, but definitely not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Spent days trying to fix this, looked at loads of solutions, and then finally found how to fix it.
I have an install of LXLE, and after switching every screensaver
setting off still got the locked screen after exactly 10 minutes...

Simply go into Synaptic and uninstall "xautolock", then reboot...
problem solved for me!