# no Terminal commands are working at all after install of Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, system-installation

I am at a loss.
All that I get are error messages. And it is not random.
All Terminal commands are reporting errors.

I was advised to re-download Lubuntu and to be sure that the MD5Sum was correct.
I did and it is correct. Then I ran a check for errors on the CD, no errors found.
Then I booted to Try Lubuntu Without Installing. It went to Desktop very fast.

I started to write some terminal commands: sudo, apt-get,mkdir, wget,sh  all give error like this one

```
sudo: command not found
```

It doesn't matter if  you combine these with other commands you will **always** get error messages.
For example when I try to install something:

```
sudo apt-get install (any Program):
```

This will yield nothing but error messsages:

```
No command sudo found, did you mean:

Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo-ldap' (universe)  
Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo' (main)
```

And so on...
I didn't write down the other error messages for apt-get...
the error list sometimes fills up half the Terminal screen.
So I tried the CD on another completely different computer.
Once again booted to the Desktop very fast.
When I started to input Terminal Commands, I see the same exact error messages.
No changes.

I am at a loss. I cannot do anything.

Is the Download itself corrupt even though the MD5 is verified correct?
I downloaded directly from the Lubuntu Home Page.

MD5SUM:
LINK:

Is there any way to fix this issue?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please post a command and the error messages that it generates.

Comment: Write from prompt `echo $PATH` and verify if you have `/bin`, `/sbin` and` `/usr/bin` in it. After try to execute `/bin/mount` to see what is mounted on your system...

Comment: If you do not have `/bin` and `/usr/bin` in your PATH variable you can add with PATH="/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:"${PATH}. Try to see if the directories exist e.g. `ls /bin`. Include information as name of the iso image you download , link,  MD5 checksum, output of `mount` and `echo $PATH` in your question editing with [this link](http://askubuntu.com/posts/484369/edit).

Answer (score 0):

Usually, all user commands are in /bin and /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin directories. So if it is not in your path try to add directories to your search path as follows:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: I am once again re-downloading and re-burning to disc. Then I will reinstall instead of utilizing Try Lubuntu Without Installing. It will be alot easier to post commands and error messages while Lubuntu is installed. That way I can work within Lubuntu without having to switch Computers.Please give me until the weekend. Thank you for all your help and patience. I really very much appreciate all the advice and guidance.

Comment: seems to be working better now. . .not as many error messages. . .however the "lock" screen keeps appearing after the screensaver initializes. . .is there a way to eliminate the lock screen? Is there a configuration file? The "Lock Screen when going for suspend/hibernate" is unchecked in the Power Manager section.

Comment: I removed light-locker but the lock screen still appears after the screensaver initializes. If there is a fix please advise. Lubuntu is working well at the moment except for the lock screen. No more errors. Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Is this what you mean? [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/130808/stop-xscreensaver-from-locking-screen-once-screensaver-starts)

Comment: I was able to fix the lock screen issue by deleting ALL light locker configuration files after deletion of light locker. Thank you for all of the assistance.

Comment: You're welcome. Good job. :)

Comment: I am learning due to all the wonderful help I have received. So it is all of you that deserve the credit! Thank you again for all of the assistance!