# Lubuntu enforces screen lock

Tags: lubuntu, lock-screen, screensaver, lock

I can't disable screen lock in Lubuntu. In Power management I have it unchecked. There is another option "Enable light locker" in the "Light locker settings". I also have this unchecked but I still see black screen after 10 minutes and when I move the mouse I have to provide a password.

I hate this behaviour in all ubuntus, but usually I can just disable it in system settings. Well not here.

So lubuntu has these settings in two places and is ignoring both.

I found this question:

[Stop Xscreensaver from locking screen once screensaver starts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130808/stop-xscreensaver-from-locking-screen-once-screensaver-starts)

According to this, I tried to remove "xscreensaver" package, but didn't have it installed at all. So this solves

**EDIT:**

What I learned so far:

- this is not magic. it affects other people as well
- it is caused by a bug in Xfce power manager:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-power-manager/+bug/1193716

Comment: there are gnome and qt versions, do you have those installed? look for `gnome-screensaver`

Comment: "gnome-screensaver" also not installed

Comment: sorry, look for `lxlock`?

Comment: ok.. so I just remove this?

Comment: damnit! apt-get remove says: "Unable to locate package lxlock"

Comment: no, it is `sudo apt-get remove lightlocker`

Comment: also can't locate lightlocker.. :(

Comment: @user568021 This is one of a few thousands of reasons why the *ubuntus are not ready for the desktop. And Ubuntu is one of the more user friendly for desktop users out there. If you need to spend time / go on stackoverflow / scratch your head, on something so elementary then it's wrong. I use some of the *ubuntus because I need a Linux OS and they are buggy when it comes to the desktop. There are bugs everywhere. The desktop environment is buggy, the addons/applets are buggy, plus the desktop setting UI is horribly designed. You often need to go online to understand "what that field means".

Comment: @user568021 but you must say that we are improving. you remember ubuntus from 5 years ago? and if i compare our latest distros, with what the dark side has done...we're winning. currently I've been trying to fix the friend's windows 8 laptop for days. pure pain..

Comment: The idea of removing an entire package or two, just to get around unwanted invocations of an individual command therein, is the opposite of good problem-solving - and might well cause _other_ problems besides. The proper way would be to track down where that command is specified and disable/alter it. The detective work can be fun...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This solution is a combination of @Jeroen's [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/526842/156787) and @A lubuntu user [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/505551/156787).

The root cause, I believe, is that the user-specific `light-locker.desktop` file doesn't override the system-wide one.  So, even if the user configures light-locker to not start at all, it still runs with the default configuration parameters.

**Warning:** This will disable system-wide default screen locking.  If you want to enable locking for a specific user, you'll need to edit the `Exec=` line in the `~/.config/autostart/light-locker.desktop` file for each user.  Configuring this through "Preferences >> Light Locker Settings" may do this (once the system-wide file is moved out of the way), but I haven't tried this.

Step 1: Disable system-wide startup of light-locker.  This will allow the per-user .desktop file to be executed instead.

`sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/light-locker.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/light-locker.desktop.bak`

To re-enable this, you would just rename the file so it no longer has the `.bak` extension.

Step 2: Edit the user-specific light-locker.desktop file

Open ~/.config/autostart/light-locker.desktop in a text editor.

Edit the line that begins `Exec=` so it is only `Exec=`. That is, there is no command specified which means light-locker won't be started.

Step 3: Reboot.

Comment: (This is really a comment on Geoffrey Hing's excellent answer but apparently I don't have enough reputation to comment, though I can post an answer - seems backwards to me.) Anyway: I did Geoffrey's Step 1, i.e. Disabled system-wide startup of light-locker: sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/light-locker.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/light-locker.desktop.bak and rebooted. I then modified the Light Locker Settings using the GUI through "Preferences >> Light Locker Settings" and my changed settings were then respected.

Comment: I don't have a file at ~/.config/autostart/light-locker.desktop

Comment: @goofballLogic That file is created once you go to `Preferences >> Light Locker Settings` and edit/save light locker configuration.

Answer (score 3):

I have found what seems a folder for autostart applications: ~/.config/autostart. In my computer, there is a .desktop file for the screen locker (light-locker.desktop). It is a sort of shortcut. If you want to know more about .desktop files and how to create  entries for the applications menu, read [this article](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Main_Menu) of the wiki of LXDE which is the Desktop of Lubuntu.

The .desktop files put in the right folder create entries for the applications menu and I suspect in this folder they start applications when the user logs in. I am not sure, but users with different autostart programs have different "shorcuts" in this folder.

I think it is worth checking your light-locker.desktop file in case the problem was that your Lubuntu installation was not able to modified it when you use the light-locker settings app.

I have also found out that users with different configurations of Light locker have different light-locker.desktop files. As sensible, the only difference is the "exec" line, which determines which app or command is executed and its arguments or options. I mean clicking on an application menu entry is similar to run its "exec" line in a shell or terminal. It is quite easy to create a new app entry for a program in the menu. I have done this task several times.

The .desktop files can be edited by opening them with leafpad which is the default plain text editor in Lunbuntu. If you do not save any change, nothing will be modified.

The "exec" line is something like this:

`Exec=light-locker --lock-after-screensaver=0 --lock-on-suspend --no-late-locking`.

If you want to know what arguments light-locker has got, you can open a shell and run `info light-locker`. I must note there are not all of its arguments. From my point of view, that information should be improved if the developers have the chance.

However, there are several users in my Lubuntu installation and they have different Light-locker settings. I can confirm you that the following options are right:

1) If you want Light-locker to lock the screen when you suspend the computer:

`Exec=light-locker --lock-after-screensaver=0 --lock-on-suspend --no-late-locking`.

2) It you do not want the previous option:

`Exec=light-locker --lock-after-screensaver=0 --no-lock-on-suspend --no-late-locking`.

A "exec" line without `--lock-after-screensaver=0` or `--no-late-locking` can cause the functionality you have described in your computer. You can check it by running `info light-locker` as I said before.

Otherwise, you could move the light-locker.desktop onto other folder and reboot to try. Before doing this latest suggestion, you'd better ask in the Lubuntu mailing list. There are people with a deeper knowledge of this OS.

Comment: Sorry I'm not following.. You are saying I should add the two options to my .desktop file? Which one.. I have these two: light-locker.desktop, screensaver-settings.desktop

Comment: I referred to the ligh-locker.desktop file. Light locker is the default screen locker of Lubuntu. If you want to know more about .desktop file read [this wiki article](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Main_Menu).

Comment: ok.. added the line you provided to the Exec= line in light-locker.desktop file... let's see what happens after some time :)

Comment: I have just edited my second post to make it clearer. I imagine you have modified the "exec" line of the file. It should not have two "exec" lines.

Comment: You might not believe this, but it simply does not work for me. Lubuntu just ignores everything I do!

Comment: I really hate mailing lists, so I try to get help on IRC, but no responses there. The channel looks like a ghost town.

Comment: Never I have entered the IRC channel, but answers in the mailing list always get a reply.

Comment: Thank you, I need a way to quickly change from unsecure to secure setting. Anyway is a bit stupid that such config files are not owned by root.

Comment: FYI, there was a light-locker.desktop file in ~/.config/autostart, but the Exec line was empty.  When I added an exec line from the example above, light-locker is still run without the command line switches, which is what the system-wide desktop file specifies.

Answer (score 1):

This solved the problem for me:

```
sudo apt-get purge light-locker light-locker-settings
```

*the answer as been modified as suggested from [kbuilds](https://askubuntu.com/users/146638/kbuilds) and [muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru)*

Comment: A `*` causes `apt-get` to treat it is a regular expression, possibly with unintended consequences. Avoid it if you can.

Comment: And as per comments elsewhere, even without coarse pattern-matching, removing a package just to work around a single issue caused by _something else_ that calls it... is a really poor approach to problem solving and might cause worse issues elsewhere.

Comment: This did work for me. Using the `*` is bad practice, but I specifically uninstalled `light-locker` and `light-locker-settings` to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the autostart applications are selected in "default application for LXSession" in preferences sub-menu (for Lubuntu 14.04)? I can see the screensaver and "screenlocker" applications checked there, but I have never tried disabling it.

Comment: This is getting ridiculous. Found both options, disabled, but it still gets ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work properly based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/505551/130555), but in newer versions of Lubuntu (15.10 in my case) there is another option that needs to be included.

My `Exec` line is:

```
Exec=light-locker --lock-after-screensaver=0 --lock-on-suspend --no-late-locking --no-lock-on-lid
```

Now the options in "power manager" work properly.

Answer (score -3):

This solved the problem for me:

```
sudo rm /etc/xdg/autostart/light-locker.desktop
```

Comment: This does indeed work, but it would be helpful to explain the consequences (disables the screen locking systemwide).  To me, this isn't terrible as it can still be enabled on a per-user basis, but I'm assuming the lack of context is the reason for the downvotes.